# Multipart/form-data with arrays

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="/test">
  <input type="hidden" name="arr[]" value="val1">
  <input type="hidden" name="arr[]" value="val2">
  <input type="hidden" name="arr[]" value="val3">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

With the controller:

```
//...
server.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.body);
});
//...
```

This returns fine with:

```
{
  arr: [
    "val1",
    "val2",
    "val3"
  ]
}
```

However, when I change the enctype to multipart/formdata

```
<form method="post" action="/test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="arr[]" value="val1">
  <input type="hidden" name="arr[]" value="val2">
  <input type="hidden" name="arr[]" value="val3">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The server now responds with:

```
{
  arr[]: "val3"
}
```

What's the issue? Is there some kind of configuration I need?

In case you're wondering, I'm also sending a file, that why I need the `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Looks more like multiparty does not handle this situation correctly. Would be interested to see what comes out. If you find no solution, try to report it under: https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/issues

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong? I have the same problem here

Comment: The array syntax is a non-standard extension to form syntax. Your body parse for url encoded data recognises it but your body parser for multipart data does not. You didn't provide a [mcve] so we don't know what body parsers you are using so we can't tell if it is because there is no support or if support just needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to the use of [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) (especially the `urlencoded` method) which, [by default](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions), works on requests with the media-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` only.

Your main application module probably has some lines like these:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

I suppose, you could just add the following to have requests of type `multipart/form-data` parsed as well:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  type: 'multipart/form-data'
}));
```

Comment: The multipart syntax is completely different to the urlencoded syntax. You can't use a parser for one with the other.

Comment: Whoops, my bad! But body-parser has no multipart syntax, you'll need a dedicated module for handling multipart requests, like busboy or multer, as mentioned in the body-parser documentation.

Comment: They're already using one (otherwise they wouldn't get the results they said they were getting), but we don't know which.

Comment: Just a wild guess: The question is tagged with `kraken.js`, so it might be [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable). The results they're seeing in the first example can be attributed to the use of the `{ extended: true }` flag of body-parser, I think.